# Load balancing K8s Pods with operator-framework

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I built a simple operator, by tweaking the memcached example. The only major difference is that I need two docker images in my pods. Got the deployment running. My test.yaml used to deploy with `kubectl`.

```
apiVersion: "cache.example.com/v1alpha1"
kind: "Memcached"
metadata:
  name: "solar-demo"
spec:
  size: 3
  group: cache.example.com
  names:
    kind: Memcached
    listKind: MemcachedList
    plural: solar-demos
    singular: solar-demo
  scope: Namespaced
  version: v1alpha1
```

I am still missing one piece though - load-balancing part. Currently, under Docker we are using the `nginx` image working as a reverse-proxy configured as:

```
upstream api_microservice {
  server api:3000;
}
upstream solar-svc_microservice {
  server solar-svc:3001;
}
server {
  listen $NGINX_PORT default;

  location /city {
    proxy_pass http://api_microservice;
  }

  location /solar {
    proxy_pass http://solar-svc_microservice;
  }

  root /html;
  location / {
    try_files /$uri /$uri/index.html /$uri.html /index.html=404;
  }
}
```

I want my cluster to expose the port `8080` and forward to ports `3000` and `3001` to my images running inside Pods.

My deployment:

```
dep := &appsv1.Deployment{
    TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
        APIVersion: "apps/v1",
        Kind:       "Deployment",
    },
    ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
        Name:      m.Name,
        Namespace: m.Namespace,
    },
    Spec: appsv1.DeploymentSpec{
        Replicas: &replicas,
        Selector: &metav1.LabelSelector{
            MatchLabels: ls,
        },
        Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec{
            ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
                Labels: ls,
            },
            Spec: v1.PodSpec{
                Containers: []v1.Container{
                    {
                        Image:   "shmukler/docker_solar-svc",
                        Name:    "solar-svc",
                        Command: []string{"npm", "run", "start-solar-svc"},
                        Ports: []v1.ContainerPort{{
                            ContainerPort: 3001,
                            Name:          "solar-svc",
                        }},
                    },
                    {
                        Image:   "shmukler/docker_solar-api",
                        Name:    "api",
                        Command: []string{"npm", "run", "start-api"},
                        Ports: []v1.ContainerPort{{
                            ContainerPort: 3000,
                            Name:          "solar-api",
                        }},
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

What do I need to add have `ingress` or something running in front of my pods?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to add have ingress or something running in front of my pods?

Yes, [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress) is designed for that kind of tasks.

`Ingress` has a `path-based` routing, which will be able  to set up the same configuration as you mentioned in your example with Nginx. Moreover, one of the most popular implementations of `Ingress` is `Nginx` as a proxy.

`Ingress` is basically a set of rules that allows traffic, otherwise dropped or forwarded elsewhere, to reach the cluster services.
Here is an example of an Ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  rules:
  - host: '' # Empty value means ‘any host’
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /city
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /solar
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 3001
```

Also, because a `Pod` is not a static thing, you should create a `Service` object which will be a static entry point of your application for `Ingress`.

Here is an example of the `Service`:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: "NAME_OF_YOUR_DEPLOYMENT"
  ports:
  - name: city
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  - name: solar
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3001
    targetPort: 3001
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did what you suggested. It shows: ```$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP             2d
solar-demo   ClusterIP   10.106.81.209   <none>        3000/TCP,3001/TCP   4m```
However, I have two containers in my Pod. How would ingress know to send 3000 to `solar-api` and 3001 to `solar-svc`

Comment: The reason is how networking in pods works and how we configured the communication from Ingress through service to the pod itself. Since the containers inside pods share all the ports and we mapped service to reach “city” on port 3000 and “solar” on port 3001, it forwards the request to the specified ports (remember to change names in config files to solar-api and solar-svc instead of my-app). You can find an article on networking inside of pods under this [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-pods-7117dd28727).